# Getting count by drilling down through relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I'm using Rails 4 and I want to get a count of votes for each individual post review for a given post.

Schema:

```
Post    PostReview    PostReviewVote
id      post_id       post_review_id
        user_id       user_id
                      voted_on_date
```

I have something like:

```
table.table.table-striped.table-hover
  thead
    tr
      th Post Name
      th Reviews Created For Post
      th Total Votes in All Reviews For Post
  tbody
    - for post in @posts
      tr
        td= post.name
        td= PostReview.where(post_id: post.id).size
        td= PostReview.where(post_id: post.id).PostReviewVotes.size
```

But it's not fetching, citing a runtime error:

```
undefined method `PostReviewVotes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Any suggestions? My models have the proper associations, FYI.

Comment: You say they have proper associations. Does `Post` have the association: `has_many :PostReviewVotes, through: PostReview` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
post.post_reviews.count
post.post_review_votes.count
```

If you have all the associations defined as you say.

or if you want a method for it...

In your Post model:

```
def post_votes_total
  self.post_review_votes.count
end
```

As long as you have defined the relationship in Post:

```
has_many :post_review_votes, through: :post_reviews
```

Since you are passing the @posts variable to the view :

```
post.post_votes_total
```

Using the built in association methods in the views is fine, but if logic gets more complicated you should really use a model method or a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues I see:

`PostReview.where(post_id: post.id)` can return more than one record.

Your relationship should be defined as `post_review_votes`, so you'd want to call `.post_review_votes` rather than `PostReviewvotes`

You might want one of the following:
`` `PostReview.where(post_id: post.id).first.post_review_votes.size ``- If you only expect one PostReview this is probably what you want.

`PostReview.where(post_id: post.id).collect{|pr| pr.post_review_votes.size}.sum` - This will take all of the post reviews, get the size of their votes, and add them together.

Or pure SQL:

`PostReviewVotes.includes(:post_review).where("post_reviews.post_id: ?", post.id).count`

Comment: I think he wants the count of `PostReview.where(post_id: post.id)` in that column, that's why he's getting a count on the number it returns.

Comment: @Beartech: That's correct. As for `.collect{}` is that really the best way to do this? Seems convoluted.

Comment: @Serg there's probably an ActiveRecord query that will generate this sum more cleanly.

Comment: Added a pure SQL approach to my answer

Comment: I think you could do a join. But I'm thinking you shouldn't be doing that kind of logic in the view. You should make some helper methods, either in the model or in a helper. That way you can just call the method in your view.

Comment: Also, I think you need another cup GeekOnCoffee, he's working with "votes" not "notes". :-)

Comment: @Beartech that means it's time for bed. Edited my answer, thanks!